# How to implement Map structure using Google Protobuf

Tags: c++, dictionary, protocol-buffers

Now I'm using Google protobuf and I want to make use of Map structure. However I find out there is no such data structure implemented in Google protobuf.

My problem is very straightforward. I have a structure with a 'Page Number(uint32_t)' and a very simple content. What I want is use this Page Number as key and the content as value. This should satisfy both the space and speed requirement. However there is no such data structure in Protobuf.

The method I use is like this:

```
message MyPageContent {
    required uint32 contentA = 1;
    required uint32 contentB = 2;
}

message MyTable {
    repeated MyPageContent table= 1;
}
```

The total number of pages is known. So at the beginning of my program I add all the pagecontent to the table with some special value(This value is used to notify the page is not there, noone should use the content.) In this way, I could implicitly use the page number to index. When a page is ready, I will change the corresponding value in the table. People directly use the page number as index to access the content. This method spends a lot of space(A lot of page is not ready and I just put some special value there to let people know its not ready.) but the accessing time is fast.

An alternative method to do something like this:

```
message MyTable {
    repeated uint32 pageNum = 1;
    repeated MyPageContent myContent = 2;
}
```

In this way, I can add a page to the table when it's ready. The size of the table should be limited in this way. However, people have to first do a linear search to find if the page is in the table. This will consume a lot of time.

Basically this is why I want to use the Map structure in protobuf. It saves both space and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way, (un)fortunately.

Protobuf is not a library for manipulating data, it's a library for serialization. So you manipulate your data in `std::map` or whatever container, and serialize it using `repeated` fields in protobuf.

Comment: This answer is out of date now -- [protobuf supports maps](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps)

Answer (score 28):

I'm not sure when this change happened, but currently (April '15) ProtoBuf [supports maps](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps):

> If you want to create an associative map as part of your data definition, protocol buffers provides a handy shortcut syntax:
>
> `map<key_type, value_type> map_field = N;`
>
> ...where the `key_type` can be any integral or string type (so, any scalar type except for floating point types and `bytes`). The `value_type` can be any type.
>
> So, for example, if you wanted to create a map of projects where each `Project` message is associated with a `string` key, you could define it like this:
>
> `map<string, Project> projects = 3;`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, it looks like the documentation is the only place this is supported. The protocol compiler won't accept it.

Comment: "The protocol compiler won't accept it." sounds like you simply have an old protoc installed. Are you sure you've got the newest version, and that that version supports ProtoBufV3?

Comment: After researching the forums I realized that this is only supported in v3, which is still in Beta. I just used a work-around for now. Thanks.

Comment: How do I fill the map from C++?

Comment: @MikeGebirge the point is that it *is* documented in the proto2 API documentation, but `protoc` 2.5.0 does not seem to support it.

Comment: @Marco this is a confusing aspect of the documentation. Proto2 is not protobuf v2.x.x in all parts of the documentation. maps are supported natively in protobuf v3.x.x in either the proto2/proto3 syntaxes.

Comment: "confusing" being the operative word here :) Thanks, @PradeepGollakota for the clarification!